# Test UNC paths from a text list and write each line with its result

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, windows-scripting

I have a text file with several DFS shares that looks as follows:

```
\\\computer1\dfsshare1  
\\\computer2\dfsshare2  
\\\computer3\dfsshare3  
\\\computer4\dfsshare4  
\\\computer5\dfsshare5
```

I want to `Test-Path` on each of them using a `Foreach-Object` function, and then list each line + `=` + its result (true or false) and add a `@` in the end of the line, all to be shown on the screen.

I tested the following:

```
$DFSList = "G:\DFS-MONITOR\DFS-List.txt"    
Get-Content $DFSList | Foreach-Object {Write-host $_'=' Test-Path $_ '@'}
```

But could not get the `Test-Path` to work after the `Write-Host` (just without it).

The expected result should be something like this, assuming the 4th DFS Share isn't available:

```
\\computer1\dfsshare1=True@
\\computer2\dfsshare2=True@
\\computer3\dfsshare3=True@
\\computer4\dfsshare4=False@
\\computer5\dfsshare5=True@
```

Comment: Why `Write-Host`?

Comment: To write on the screen. It could be anything else that writes on the screen. Tee-Object, Write-Output... etc.

Comment: Wrap `Test-Path` in parens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, If you want to pass the *result/output* of a command/script/cmdlet to another command/script/cmdlet, you need to wrap the command providing the results in parentheses:

```
Write-Host $_ '=' (Test-Path $_) '@'
```

Comment: Thank you. The weird thing is that Test-Path's output always gives me a space before the result word, ` true `. Is there a better way to avoid this space? I wanted to have it right before the "=" mark.

Comment: You can do it using the `-f` operator. `Write-Host ("{0}={1}@" -f $_,(Test-Path $_)`. I'd strongly urge you to bookmark [SS64's PowerShell section](https://ss64.com/ps/) as a quick PowerShell reference.